# JSON Error: I don't know what type of json file i have. Object or Array? "A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1"

Tags: java, arrays, json, object

This is my JSON file

```
{
"PartDetails": {
    "MyPricing": [{
        "BreakQuantity": 200,
        "UnitPrice": 0.3787,
        "TotalPrice": 75.74
    }, {
        "BreakQuantity": 600,
        "UnitPrice": 0.2932,
        "TotalPrice": 175.92
    }, {
        "BreakQuantity": 1000,
        "UnitPrice": 0.2525,
        "TotalPrice": 252.5
    }, {
        "BreakQuantity": 2600,
        "UnitPrice": 0.25,
        "TotalPrice": 650
    }]
}
```

This is part of my java code. I am trying to pull out MyPricing. I am very new to JSON. Some help would be nice. I don't quite know the syntax that well yet. I have been watching some videos to this point to no avail.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:/Users/Public/Documents/JSON/JSONFile.json"));
        // String jsonString="";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(obj.toString()).getJSONObject("PartDetails");

        System.out.println(jsonObject);

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("MyPricing");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray .length(); i++) {
            JSONObject _jObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject   _jObjTarget = _jObj.getJSONObject("target");
            String _indicator_name = _jObjTarget.getString("indicator_name");
            System.out.println("Indicator Name : " + _indicator_name);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Missing } after ] ?

Comment: This is a file I am pulling in from a website. It is actually very long. I just figured I would post some of it. Please don't look too much into the syntax of the JSON file.

Comment: Update: I added this line
    System.out.println(jsonObject.get("MyPricing"));
It gave me 
    [{"UnitPrice":0.3787,"BreakQuantity":200,"TotalPrice":75.74},{"UnitPrice":0.2932,"BreakQuantity":600,"TotalPrice":175.92},{"UnitPrice":0.2525,"BreakQuantity":1000,"TotalPrice":252.5},{"UnitPrice":0.25,"BreakQuantity":2600,"TotalPrice":650}]
but i am still getting the same error.

Comment: can you post the error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("MyPricing"); -creates a new json array out of the string "MyPricing" (the string is not an array so this fails)
```

try:

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("MyPricing"); - this takes the array that lies inside your object
```

Comment: Syntax error. It does not like obj.getJSONArray There is a squiggly link under getJSONArray.

Comment: jsonObject.getJSONArray is more like it. i've began to get into my for loop now.

Comment: When calling .getJSONObject("target"); what are you trying to get?

Comment: I'm not trying to get anything at that point. I haven't dived into that yet. I will come back and ask more questions. But, I'd like to try to figure out the rest for now. You have got me further than I was.
Thanks!

Comment: Updated for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    Object unitPrice = jObj.get("UnitPrice");
    Object breakQty = jObj.get("BreakQuantity");
    Object totalPrice = jObj.get("TotalPrice");

    System.out.println("Unit Price : " + unitPrice);
    System.out.println("Break Quantity : " + breakQty);
    System.out.println("Total Price : " + totalPrice);
   }

Comment: Why can't i get my comments to look like a code block?

Comment: As far as I know comments can not contain code blocks

Comment: I recomend you take a look at getJsonString and getJsonNumber http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html